# dataTables table row not linking to URL

Tags: datatables

I am using dataTables at http://communitychessclub.com/test.php and getting ajax data that looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
{
"game": "5086",
"date": "09/02/2013",
"event": "135th NYS Ch.",
"eco": "B08",
"white": "Jones, Igor",
"white_rating": "2393",
"black": "Smith, Efim",
"black_rating": "2268"
},
```

I have this incomplete code and want to make the table row clickable such that a click will link to 'basic.php?game="data:game"'

```
**$("#cccr tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function(e) {
//rest of the code here
});**
```

What I am asking is what code replaces "//rest of the code here" ? Is it something to do with: window.location.href ?

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there but the delegate isn't required:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#example").DataTable();
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
        var row_date = table.row(this).data();
        console.log(row_date[0]);
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/search?q"+row_date[0];
    });
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/vkauquov/), it won't change the URI though as it'd be trying to change the source of an iframe... probably not an issue in your use case though.